# Not able to connect ebs.example.com from host Windows10

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox

It might be a basic error while installing the [Oracle E-Business Suite 12.1.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Applications#Oracle_E-Business_Suite) but after days of trying I am not able to connect to *ebs.example.com* from my host Windows 10 browser.

What my settings are:

1. My `DB` and `APPS` tier is up and running.
2. `ifconfig` details from my Linux VirtualBox:

   ```
   inet addr 192.168.56.1
   ```
3. My Windows 10 `ipconfig` details:

   ```
   Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
      Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
      Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::90d1:3af9:e5d1:5bb3%11
      IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.104
      Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
      Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   ```
4. I am able to ping `192.168.56.1` from my host.
5. I have set my `Network` as `host-only network` in VirtualBox.
6. `Hosts` file details from Windows:

   ```
   192.168.56.1 ebs.example.com ebs
   ```

**Problem:**

I am not able to login to the Oracle EBS page. It is showing `This site can't be reached` for the URL *http://ebs.example.com:8000*.

*Additional Screenshot:*

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Is there a firewall enabled on the guest machine? If so, is port 8000 open?

Comment: @n8te let me check using `netstat`, correct me if i am wrong!

Comment: No, netstat will show you if the port is listening but does not reflect whether the firewall is blocking the port.

Comment: @n8te okay ..i used `netstat -nat | grep :8000` so it is showing port is listening...let me check whether firewall is blocking!

Comment: @n8te i have turned off the firewall using these command `/etc/init.d/iptables save` then 
`/etc/init.d/iptables stop`...still same issue

Comment: Can you give me the name and version of the Linux distro you're running on your guest.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem connecting to my Oracle EBS 12.6 Appliance VM on a Windows 2012 server that I had just installed. I resolved by switchng to using Internet Explorer and Installing Java on the Windows 2012 OS on the host. I had not installed Java on the machine. If Java is already installed, check if the security is set to medium(lowered) on the Java Control Panel.